# In 1D FDTD, Do we expect power oscillations at PEC reclecting boundary?

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, finite-differences

Basically I am trying to check if my 1D FDTD code works fine and how to write quantity that is conserved all the way.

In 1D FDTD should we expect that the power is conserved when the pulse is being reflected off a perfect electric conductor boundary PEC ? How to write conservation law for the instantaneous pointing vector?

I am looking not at the energy but at the normalized sum(EE*)(time) (sum (over space) of the E field squared ).

sum(EE*)(time) is function of time.

On the plot is initial E field over E field at time t
( sum(EE*)(time)/sum(sum(EE*)(initial) )

Ylimit[1-1E-10 1+1E-10]
[image]
Ylimit[1-1E-15 1+1E-15]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a PEC is a perfect mirror, so energy is conserved in the system.

Comment: Thank you. This is just sum(E.*conj(E)), it is conserved to 1E^-15 away from the walls even after reflection, but not during the time of the reflection. Does sum(E.*conj(E)) have to be conserved at the reflection boundary?

Comment: It looks like it is basically conserved at all times. You see a little ripple in your first plot at the time of the reflection, but that is tiny.